# Regex - Lookahead for pattern through newlines

Tags: c#, regex

Still learning Regex, and am having trouble getting my head wrapped around the lookahead concept. Similar data to my question here - [Matching multiple lines up until a sepertor line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738742/matching-multiple-lines-up-until-a-sepertor-line) , say I have the following lines handed to me by the user:

```
 0000AA.The horizontal coordinates are valid at the epoch date displayed above.
 0000AA.The epoch date for horizontal control is a decimal equivalence
 0000AA.of Year/Month/Day.
 0000AA
 [..]
```

So a really simple Regex is `@^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}\.(?<noteline>.*)`, where  would give me every line. Fantastic. :) However, I'd like a lookahead (or a condition?) that would look at the next line and tell me if the line has the code WITHOUT a '.'. (i.e. If the NEXT line would match `@^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}[^\.]`

Trying the lookahead, I get hits on the first two lines (because the following line has '.' after the code) but not on the last.

*Edit*: Using the regex above, or the one offered below gives me all lines, but I'd like to know IF a blank line (line with AA0000 code, but no '.' afterwards) follows. For example, when I get to the match on the line `of Year/Month/Day`, I'd like to know **IF** that line is followed by a blank line (or not). (Like with a grouping name that's not spaces or empty, for high-level example.)

*Edit 2*: I may be mis-using the 'lookahead' term. Going back over .NET's regex, I see something referred to as a Alternation Construct, but not sure if that could be used here.

Thanks! 
Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, and hit and misses, I'm certain now that it can't be done - or, rather - it CAN be but would be prohibitively difficult - easier to do it in code.

To refrain, I was looking at a multiline string (document), where *every* line was preceded by a 6-digit code. Some lines - the lines I'm interested in - have a '.' after the 6-digit code, and then open text. I was hoping there would be a way to get me each line in a group, along with a flag letting me know if the next line has no free-text entry. (No '.' after the 6-digit code.) I.e. Two line data entry would give me two matches on the document. First match would have the line's text in the group called 'notetext', and the group 'lastline' would be empty. The second line would have the second part of the entered note in 'notetext', and the group 'lastline' would have something (anything, content wouldn't matter.)

From what I understand, lookaheads are zero-width assertions, so that if it matches, the returnable value is still empty. Without using lookahead, the match for 'lastline' would consume the next line's code, making the 'notetext' skip that line (giving me every *other* line of text.) So, I would need to have some back-reference to revert back to.

By this time, it'd be easier (code-wise) to simply get all the lines, and add up text until I get to the end of their notes. (Looping over then entire document, which can't be more than 200 lines as opposed to looping through the regex-matched lines, and the ease of reading the code for future modifications would out-weigh any slight speed advantage the regex could get me.

Thanks guys -
-Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the option `RegexOptions.Multiline`. It changes the meaning of `^` and `$` making them match the beginning and the end of ervery line instead the beginning and end of the entire string.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, 
                            @"^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}\..*$?(?!^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}[^.])",
                            RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

The negative look ahead is

```
find(?!suffix)
```

It matches a position not preceeding a suffix. Don't escape the dot within the brackets `[ ]`. The bracket disables the special meaning of most characters anyway.

I also added `.*$?` making the pattern match until the end of the current line. The `?` is required in order make `*` *lazy*. Otherwise it is *greedy*, meaning that will try to get as many characters as possible and possibly match several lines at a time.

---

If you need only the number part, you can capture it in a group by enclosing it within parentheses.

```
(^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2})\..*$?(?!^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}[^.])
```

You can then get the group like this

```
string number = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Note: Group #0 represents the entire match.

Comment: Thanks! I was using multiline, I had forgotten to mention that. This works, but misses the main point of the question (my bad, since I wasn't clear originally.) I edited my question to be more clear!

Comment: My example returns lines that are not preceeding a line that has a number without a dot after it. Is it what you mean by blank line? If you mean lines only having a number you could change the negative lookahead by `(?!^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}$)`. If the line should be completely emtpy by `(?!^$)`.